# QGIS for mac acting strange after upgrade to 2.16

Tags: qgis, saga

I'm running OSX 10.10.5 and just upgraded QGIS from 2.14 to 2.16.

1st. the installed GDAL 2.1 wasn't registering when using gdalinfo --version. It still showed 1.11... So I used [MAPBOX GUIDE](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/gdal/) to get the 2.1 to be added to my PATH. But running SAGA tools from Processing seems to be broken ex. running Fill Sink only results in ERROR.

I tried to re install the 2.14 again (removing qgis.app and ~/.qgis2)

Now 2.14 which worked earlier is not working properly either!

Could anyone give me a clue how to properly install either 2.14 or 2.16 on a mac so both SAGA tools and specially Raster tools will work.

Comment: Running SAGA Fill Sink gives this ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details

Comment: found this page because I have the same error with the VRM algorithm in SAGA. none of the saga algorithms I've tried work in 2.16 on a mac

Comment: I have the same error with the SAGA Fill sinks, qgis 2.16.3 and as well have OS X. Have you come to any solution yet?